# Object Query Language referrers

Tags: java, oql

I'm trying to analyze a heap dump to determine if my hibernate cache settings are the cause.

Many instances of the object in question are referred to by "org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.IdentityMap".  How can I construct an OQL query to return me the exact number of instances of my object that are referred to by hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, you may be able to get `dominatorof()` function to work, try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ".*" o WHERE classof(dominatorof(o)).@displayName.contains("class org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.IdentityMap")
```

But this will make MAT go through every object in the heap, so it will take a long time to return results (assuming you have a reasonably large heap). However the real problem is that I find the `dominatorof()` function to be inconsistent, so you may not find every object. If you have a list of classes, then you may be able to speed up the query and also confirm that you are getting the right dominators. E.g., if X and Y are the class names, you can use "X|Y" as the regex instead of ".*" and also run this query to see what you get:

```
SELECT dominatorof(o) FROM "X|Y" o
```